# Is the amount of dark matter per galaxy the same as you look back through time (further away from earth)?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, astrophysics, dark-matter

In the hope that it may inform us about the development/evolution (if any) of dark matter over time, are there any differences (eg. in structure or concentration) in the dark matter at large radial distances from earth compared with closer radial distances.

I imagine this could be answered by using things like the lensing data of galaxies at varying distances from earth.

Answer (score 0):

No. Galaxies collide and merge. The galaxies of the current epoch are thus larger and contain more matter, dark and baryonic, than the galaxies in the past.

Comment: I wouldn’t have thought that galaxies colliding and merging necessarily meant that galaxies of the current epoch contain more dark matter. Looking at the bullet cluster image, the dark matter seems to separate from the visible matter during collision, which makes me wonder if collisions could have the opposite effect.

Comment: Galaxies are mostly made of dark matter. While there may be some temporary separation, in the long run the visible matter follows the dark matter, since it has the mass.